# jquery function runs first to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working with AngularJS and have a code in jQuery that should run once loaded the DOM, but I realized with alert () that .ready appeared before the view was ready and therefore the code could not run, it does not give Error code simply does not work

my code in jQuery

```
    $('.form-control').on('focus blur', function (e) {
    $(this).parents('.form-group').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value.length > 0));
}).trigger('blur');
```

How can I achieve load this code once the list view but globally?, Which may be present in all view

Comment: Instead of relying on jQuery's document.ready, which actually fires when the DOMContentLoaded event fires, you can use straight JavaScript and set up `window.addEventListener("load", yourFunction)`, which fires when all the DOM resources are done loading.

Comment: Are you loading the jquery at the top of the body tag or just before body tag closes ?

Comment: I'm loading the code in the head

Comment: probe by placing the code at the end of the body and footer, and still does not work, if I add a function time of about 6 seconds there if the code works

Comment: Angular has it's  own events for when the view is rendered, for instance [`$viewContentLoaded`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)

Comment: I also tried with that but I want to be present in all view

Comment: Did you try just delegating the event to an element that exists on pageload

Comment: as mentioned earlier, if I wrap the code in a time of 6 seconds, the code works without problem, but I think it is not the optimal solution

Comment: I was thinking more in the lines `$(document).on('focus blur', '.form-control', function (e) {...`

Comment: yes, that also try

Comment: there maybe something wrong, since probe with $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', 
function(event){ ... });  and according to documentation it runs after the sun loaded and is running at half